# how to get dark mode in files in elementary OS?

Tags: settings, pantheon-files, pantheon, files, tweak-tool

I've Searched many websites and blogs regarding this issue and none are successful so far so i thought i could post my question in the forums.I've tried installing repositories and stuff many things i saw on the internet and they all ended up nowhere please help me with this.How can I get Dark Mode on Files application on elementary OS ?!

Answer (score 2):

actually, at least in my case, selecting "Prefer dark variant" under the "Appearence" tab of Elementary-tweaks works globally for every application

You just need to install elementary tweaks as explained here - see [here](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) for installation instructions

See a screenshot taken a while ago[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Files does not have a "prefer-dark-style" setting unlike Code and Terminal.

You can run it in dark mode by launching from the command line with `GTK_THEME=elementary:dark io.elementary.files` but this will not work when launching from the dock or Applications menu.

Unfortunately, linking the above command to a custom keyboard shortcut using Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Custom does not work either for some reason.

Note that Files is not currently dark-theme aware so some aspects of the appearance may not be ideal.
`

Comment: Work is ongoing within elementary as to how to support a system prefer-dark variant